# Unable to find a model that matches key

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Upgraded Swagger from 2.9.2 to 3.0.0 based on steps below:

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#migrating-from-existing-2-x-version

In new version, though functionality is working fine, following ERROR is printed in logs when hitting the "/swagger-ui/index.html".

Using springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0. Would appreciate your inputs.

> [ReferenceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter] Unable to find a
> model that matches key
> ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='java.time',
> name='LocalDate'}, viewDiscriminator=null,
> validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}

Answer (score 0):

As per the Springfox documentation

http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#answers-to-common-questions-and-problems

> The way to correctly map the "Date" and "DateTime" types to their
> corresponding swagger types:
>
> Substitute "Date" types (java.util.LocalDate, org.joda.time.LocalDate)
> by java.sql.Date.
>
> Substitute "DateTime" types (java.util.ZonedDateTime,
> org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, …​) by java.util.Date.

```
 docket
    .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
    .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
```

Example of Docket bean

```
@Bean
public Docket api()
{

    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) //
            .select() //
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test")) //
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*")).build() //
            .apiInfo(apiInfo()) //
            .pathMapping("/") //
            .forCodeGeneration(true) //
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class) //
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);

    return docket;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error.  Would you please publish the entire bean?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but to me this problem arised because I had a JsonSubTyped generic inheritance where one of the children had List<LocalDate> and  List<LocalDateTime> as their parameter. The fix was - for me - to include extra rules for the types as follows:

```
myDocket.alternateTypeRules(
                        AlternateTypeRules.newRule(typeResolver.resolve(List.class, LocalDate.class), typeResolver.resolve(List.class, java.sql.Date.class)), 
                        AlternateTypeRules.newRule(typeResolver.resolve(List.class, LocalDateTime.class), typeResolver.resolve(List.class, java.util.Date.class)))
```

The replacement classes are from the official site.